# Meaning of ישב אהלים and grammar

Tags: sources-mekorot, grammar-dikduk, parashat-toldot

We read last Shabbat parshat Toldot in which we find the famous statement in Bereshit 25:27

> וְיַעֲקֹב֙ אִ֣ישׁ תָּ֔ם **יֹשֵׁ֖ב אֹהָלִֽים**

The mefarshim deals with the meaning of ישב אהלים, some like Rashi focuses more on the word "tents":

> ישב אהלים DWELLING IN TENTS — the tent of Shem and the tent of Eber (Genesis Rabbah 63:10).

Others like Rabbi Abraham Ibn Ezra and RaSHbaM focus their explanation more on the combination of the words ישב אהלים : 
Ibn Ezra comments as follow:

> And Jacob "stayed in the tents:" And it seems likely that its meaning is like "those who dwell in tents and amidst herds." (Gen. 4:20)

RaSHbaM comments as follow:

> ישב אהלים, tending his father’s flocks as we explained already in connection with 4,20 ישב אהל ומקנה.

After a quick look at the main other mefarshim, it seems that nobody exactly questioned the fact that the Torah says ישב **אהלים** and not ישב **ב**אהלים.

What is the difference of meaning between ישב אהלים and ישב באהלים in biblical Hebrew?

Comment: Frequently, verbs are used as nouns, in Hebrew. So the word ישב could mean either "sitting" (verb) or "one who sits" (noun). It would help if you could cite a verse that has ישב באהלים for Tanac"h. I'm unaware of one. If you cannot find one, that last question is not relevant.

Comment: @DanF, on Succos do you say לשב בסוכה or לשב סוכה? And I know it is not in Tanach but still it is relevant

Comment: Your comment ignored or misunderstood the first part of Dan's. Present-tense verbs are nouns (and can be in the construct state). "To" infinitives aren't.

Comment: I still don't understand his point. How can we translate " sitting" or "one who sits" in tents from ישב אהלים since the ב which means in is missing? There are only 2 instances in the Torah for ישב אהלים and ישב אהל. Elsewhere in the Torah we find it with ב for instance בסוכות תשבו or יושב בהר...

Comment: msh210 makes a good point, and I'll leave you to discuss that further with him / her. But what I stated is similar in English. In English it's called a "gerund". An example - "Visiting professor" - Yes, it is ambiguous, but the point is "visiting" could be a verb or an adjective that describes the type of professor.